# Monochromatic loop in plane

Tags: combinatorics, coloring, ramsey-theory

Suppose all the points in the plane are coloured with two colours. Are we guaranteed to find a continuous closed monochromatic path in the plane ?

I believe the answer is yes, and then what if countable infinite colours are used ?

If the answer is no, then what if it's just a path (not necessarily a loop) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Colour all points $(x,y)$ with $x$ rational red, all points with $x$ irrational blue.
Then any monochromatic path is contained in a vertical line.

Using the Axiom of Choice, we can get a colouring with no monochromatic paths at all.
The set of paths in the plane has cardinality $c$.  Index them by the first ordinal of cardinality $c$.  Then using transfinite induction, we can produce disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that every path contains at least one member of $A$ and at least one member of $B$.  Colour $A$ red and $B$ blue; it doesn't matter what you do to $(A \cup B)^c$.

Comment: With $3$ colours I believe there is a constructive colouring with no monochromatic paths. Namely, what if you colour a point  red if both coordinates are rational, blue if both coordinates are irrational, and white in all other cases?

Comment: `we can produce disjoint sets A and B such that ...`, how do you do that? This is the main part of a proof.

Comment: Usual transfinite induction trick.  For each ordinal $\alpha$ of cardinality $< c$, you'll choose two points on the path corresonding to $\alpha$ that haven't yet been assigned, put one in $A$ and the other in $B$
(the choice is possible because the path has $c$ points and cardinality $< c$ points were assigned by cardinals $< \alpha$).